# How to determine number of records in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm fairly new to Oracle SQL and would like to know if anyone has any examples of how to do the following:

1. I'd like to return the number of rows that exist in the following SQL Statement listed below. This SQL will be part of a larger SQL statement and I will be passing in the EMPLID identifier into the subquery.  The result needs to be one value displaying the total number of records that match the SQL below.  'xyz' will eventually be passing in an employee's job position number using a reference from the parent SQL... ie: jbe.POSITION_NBR
2. My SQL:

   SELECT cjbe.EMPLID FROM PS_JOB cjbe
   WHERE cjbe.POSITION_NBR = 'xyz'
   GROUP BY cjbe.EMPLID
3. I'd like to know how I can pass in the poarent value of POSITION_NBR (I think I use jbe.POSITION_NBR) into my subquery and then return the total count of the EMPLID's found within that subquery.

Thanks for your help.

Original Parent SQL is here:

```
SELECT jbe.EMPLID "Employee_ID", REPLACE(nam.NAME,',',', ') "Name", jbe.HR_STATUS "HR_Status" , jbe.REG_TEMP "Reg/Temp" ,jbe.FULL_PART_TIME "FT/PT" ,jbe.SAL_ADMIN_PLAN "Emp_Type" ,jbe.DEPTID "Dept_ID" ,dpt.descr "Dept_Name" ,
(SELECT Min(pj.EFFDT) AS HIRE_DT_1
 FROM PS_JOB pj
 WHERE pj.EMPLID=jbe.emplid
     AND action IN('HIR',
                   'REH')
     AND pj.empl_rcd = 0) "Emp_Hired_Into_Pos_Dt" , jbe.POSITION_NBR "Position_Num" ,
(SELECT MIN(EFFDT)
 FROM PS_JOB
 WHERE 1=1
     AND POSITION_NBR = jbe.POSITION_NBR) "Position_Orig_Created_On" , pos.DESCR "Position_Job_Title" ,dist.ACCT_CD "Budget" ,dist.DIST_PCT "Distribution" ,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM
     (SELECT cjbe.EMPLID
      FROM PS_JOB cjbe
      WHERE cjbe.POSITION_NBR = jbe.POSITION_NBR
      GROUP BY cjbe.EMPLID)) "Qty_In_Position?"


FROM PS_JOB jbe,
 PS_NAMES nam,
 PS_JOB_EARNS_DIST dist,
 PS_POSITION_DATA pos,
 ps_dept_tbl dpt

WHERE (dist.EMPLID = jbe.EMPLID
   AND dist.EMPL_RCD = jbe.EMPL_RCD
   AND dist.EFFDT = jbe.EFFDT
   AND dist.EFFSEQ = jbe.EFFSEQ
   AND (jbe.EFFDT =
            (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT)
             FROM PS_JOB A_ED
             WHERE jbe.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID
                 AND jbe.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD
                 AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
        AND jbe.EFFSEQ =
            (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ)
             FROM PS_JOB A_ES
             WHERE jbe.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID
                 AND jbe.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD
                 AND jbe.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT)
        AND jbe.EMPL_RCD = 0
        AND jbe.HR_STATUS = 'A'
        AND REGEXP_LIKE (SUBSTR(jbe.POSITION_NBR,1,2), '^S[0-9]')
        AND jbe.EMPLID = nam.EMPLID
        AND nam.EFFDT =
            (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT)
             FROM PS_NAMES B_ED
             WHERE nam.EMPLID = B_ED.EMPLID
                 AND nam.NAME_TYPE = B_ED.NAME_TYPE
                 AND B_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
        AND nam.NAME_TYPE = 'PRI'))

    AND pos.position_nbr(+) = jbe.position_nbr
AND pos.effdt=
    (SELECT max(p2.effdt)
     FROM ps_position_data p2
     WHERE p2.position_nbr=pos.position_nbr
         AND p2.effdt<=sysdate)
AND dpt.deptid(+) = jbe.deptid
AND dpt.setid(+) = jbe.setid_dept
AND (dpt.EFFDT=
         (SELECT MAX(d2.EFFDT)
          FROM PS_DEPT_TBL d2
          WHERE dpt.DEPTID=d2.DEPTID
              AND jbe.SETID_DEPT=d2.SETID
              AND d2.EFFDT<=SYSDATE))

    AND (
         (SELECT MIN(EFFDT)
          FROM PS_JOB
          WHERE 1=1
              AND POSITION_NBR = jbe.POSITION_NBR) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01-JAN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('31-DEC-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
     OR
         (SELECT Min(pj.EFFDT) AS HIRE_DT_1
          FROM PS_JOB pj
          WHERE pj.EMPLID=jbe.emplid
              AND action IN('HIR',
                            'REH')
              AND pj.empl_rcd = 0) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01-JAN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('31-DEC-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
ORDER BY jbe.POSITION_NBR
```

Comment: How about you post your table table structures, some sample data, and the result your hoping to get?

Comment: Good idea Mark and thanks for the recommendation.

The SQL returns the following data:
Row 1: 001247855
Row 2: 008915647
Row 3: 005474111. 

I would like to show 3 as the result since there are 3 records.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Please clarify what item 3 is in your question.

Comment: I've tried using **SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(
SELECT cjbe.EMPLID FROM PS_JOB cjbe
WHERE cjbe.POSITION_NBR = jbe.POSITION_NBR
GROUP BY cjbe.EMPLID
)**  But I get the following error: ORA-00904: "JBE"."POSITION_NBR": invalid identifier

Comment: For item 3, I'm trying to pass in the position number and my subquery doesn't recognize it from the jbe alias.  **WHERE cjbe.POSITION_NBR = jbe.POSITION_NBR** is causing the error apparently.  Thanks for help a newbie on this.

Comment: What is jbe?  You haven't defined that anywhere.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of using a subquery.  It's still unclear to me what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your parent SQL:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM
     (SELECT cjbe.EMPLID
      FROM PS_JOB cjbe
      WHERE cjbe.POSITION_NBR = jbe.POSITION_NBR
      GROUP BY cjbe.EMPLID)) "Qty_In_Position?"
```

jbe.POSITION_NBR is not available because you are inside a second nested subquery.  It is available one level up (inside the first subquery where you have SELECT COUNT(*)).

The parent and subquery should look like this:

```
SELECT jbe.EMPLID "Employee_ID", REPLACE(nam.NAME,',',', ') "Name", jbe.HR_STATUS "HR_Status" , jbe.REG_TEMP "Reg/Temp" ,jbe.FULL_PART_TIME "FT/PT" ,jbe.SAL_ADMIN_PLAN "Emp_Type" ,jbe.DEPTID "Dept_ID" ,dpt.descr "Dept_Name" ,
(SELECT Min(pj.EFFDT) AS HIRE_DT_1
 FROM PS_JOB pj
 WHERE pj.EMPLID=jbe.emplid
     AND action IN('HIR',
                   'REH')
     AND pj.empl_rcd = 0) "Emp_Hired_Into_Pos_Dt" , jbe.POSITION_NBR "Position_Num" ,
(SELECT MIN(EFFDT)
 FROM PS_JOB
 WHERE 1=1
     AND POSITION_NBR = jbe.POSITION_NBR) "Position_Orig_Created_On" , pos.DESCR "Position_Job_Title" ,dist.ACCT_CD "Budget" ,dist.DIST_PCT "Distribution" ,
(SELECT count(distinct cjbe.EMPLID)
          FROM PS_JOB cjbe
          WHERE cjbe.POSITION_NBR = jbe.POSITION_NBR) "Qty_In_Position?"
FROM PS_JOB jbe,
 PS_NAMES nam,
 PS_JOB_EARNS_DIST dist,
 PS_POSITION_DATA pos,
 ps_dept_tbl dpt

WHERE (dist.EMPLID = jbe.EMPLID
   AND dist.EMPL_RCD = jbe.EMPL_RCD
   AND dist.EFFDT = jbe.EFFDT
   AND dist.EFFSEQ = jbe.EFFSEQ
   AND (jbe.EFFDT =
            (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT)
             FROM PS_JOB A_ED
             WHERE jbe.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID
                 AND jbe.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD
                 AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
        AND jbe.EFFSEQ =
            (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ)
             FROM PS_JOB A_ES
             WHERE jbe.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID
                 AND jbe.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD
                 AND jbe.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT)
        AND jbe.EMPL_RCD = 0
        AND jbe.HR_STATUS = 'A'
        AND REGEXP_LIKE (SUBSTR(jbe.POSITION_NBR,1,2), '^S[0-9]')
        AND jbe.EMPLID = nam.EMPLID
        AND nam.EFFDT =
            (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT)
             FROM PS_NAMES B_ED
             WHERE nam.EMPLID = B_ED.EMPLID
                 AND nam.NAME_TYPE = B_ED.NAME_TYPE
                 AND B_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
        AND nam.NAME_TYPE = 'PRI'))

    AND pos.position_nbr(+) = jbe.position_nbr
AND pos.effdt=
    (SELECT max(p2.effdt)
     FROM ps_position_data p2
     WHERE p2.position_nbr=pos.position_nbr
         AND p2.effdt<=sysdate)
AND dpt.deptid(+) = jbe.deptid
AND dpt.setid(+) = jbe.setid_dept
AND (dpt.EFFDT=
         (SELECT MAX(d2.EFFDT)
          FROM PS_DEPT_TBL d2
          WHERE dpt.DEPTID=d2.DEPTID
              AND jbe.SETID_DEPT=d2.SETID
              AND d2.EFFDT<=SYSDATE))

    AND (
         (SELECT MIN(EFFDT)
          FROM PS_JOB
          WHERE 1=1
              AND POSITION_NBR = jbe.POSITION_NBR) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01-JAN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('31-DEC-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
     OR
         (SELECT Min(pj.EFFDT) AS HIRE_DT_1
          FROM PS_JOB pj
          WHERE pj.EMPLID=jbe.emplid
              AND action IN('HIR',
                            'REH')
              AND pj.empl_rcd = 0) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01-JAN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('31-DEC-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
ORDER BY jbe.POSITION_NBR
```

Comment: Confirmed...it work and thanks to you Mark.  I truly appreciate your assistance.  This was my first time using Stack Overflow and it was a very positive experience due to you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Assume you will pass in EMPLID and POSITION_NBR, you only need this: 
   SELECT count(EMPLID) FROM PS_JOB cjbe
   WHERE cjbe.POSITION_NBR = 'xyz'
   AND cjbe.EMPLID=EMPLID (this is what you passed into subquery)
2. Here is an examaple
   select a.EMPLID, a.POSITION_NBR, 
   --this part is your subquery:
   (SELECT count(EMPLID) FROM PS_JOB cjbe
   WHERE cjbe.POSITION_NBR = a.POSITION_NBR
   AND cjbe.EMPLID=a.EMPLID) count_of_emplid
   from a